# How to get case-sensitive data with rails query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Assuming there is a community who has both "apple" and "APPLE" tags.

Then if I execute this with the param "apple"

```
@communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where(tags: { name: params[:tag] })
```

In result page, 2 sets of the same community come appears.
It's probably because it's fetching with the params[:tag] for both upper case and lower case.

How can I strict this and make it not `like` search?
I want case-sensitive and complete match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enclosing attribute name in binary.

```
 @communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where(['binary(tags.name) = ?', params[:tag]])
```

Comment: Thanks!!! both of them didn't work. so I took the idea from your binary() then I did `@communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where('binary(tags.name)' => params[:tag])`  but it still won't work:(

Comment: `@communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where('tags.name' => params[:tag])` This works but this fetches both "apple" and "APPLE"

Comment: I am not getting what is joins (taggings: :tag) means.. can you explain bit?

Comment: I'm using the gem called "acts_as_taggable". Usually this could be called easily by the dault method of this gem. just like this `Community.tagged_with(params[:tag])` However it won't work for few tags somehow. I found out it's because of collation thing.

Comment: this gem automatically created 2 tables. but no model. tables are "Taggings" and "Tags". In taggings, it has "taggable_type, ""taggable_id", and "tag_id" this is polymorphic

Comment: Then in "Tags" table it has name attribute which is actual value of "tag" itself. Like "Apple"

Comment: As long as there is no model file, I think I cannot do ActiveRecord thing here. That's why I'm tryin to fetch by SQL code

Comment: @communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where(['binary(tags.name) = ?', params[:tag]])  try this

Comment: ohhhhh myyyyyy you are my saver!!!!!!!!! Thanks so much. could you please put it in answer so that I can vote up?